# shutil make_archive resulting in nested .zip files

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, shutil

I've been trying to use [`make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) from `shutil` library.

Here is the code (with comprehensive comments):

```
from shutil import make_archive
make_archive(
  'zipfile_name', 
  'zip',           # archive format
  root_dir=None,   # current working dir if None
  base_dir=None)   # cwd if None
```

Here is an example of directory tree:

```
folder
│   script.py
└───subfolder1
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
└───subfolder2
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
...
```

If I run my script (with code above), the result is:

```
folder
│   script.py
└───subfolder1
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
└───subfolder2
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
└───zipfile_name.zip
│   │   same content as above (like expected)
│   │   zipfile_name.zip

...
```

Why is an additional `zipfile_name.zip` is created? Also, note that the second archive can't be open since it is invalid. I understand if no one has ever faced this issue before, but maybe my parameters are wrong and this is why I'm asking.

Comment: @ekhumoro Isn't the linked duplicate newer than my question ? Why would this thread be closed and not the other one ?

Comment: Your question didn't have any answers when the other one was asked, so neither could be marked as a duplicate at the time. There isn't much to choose between the two questions now, except that the other one has had a little more activity (i.e. the comments). Both questions still have value, so the important thing was to link them together so that others can find them more easily,

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this problem. Here's a simple trick to solve the issue: use a relative path as the `base_name`:

```
from shutil import make_archive
make_archive(
  '../zipfile_name', 
  'zip',           # archive format
  root_dir=None,   # current working dir if None
  base_dir=None)   # cwd if None
```

The archive will be created in the parent directory, not interfering with the directory that is being archived.