# Stop shutil.make_archive adding archive to itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive, shutil

I have `App` dir inside `Release` dir

```
$ cd Release
$ tree
.
`-- App
    |-- App.exe
    ..........
```

and I am trying to create `App-1.0.zip` in the `Release` dir containg `App` with all its content. That is after unpacking `App-1.0.zip` I would get this `App` dir.

I tried `shutil.make_archive` but when I do this

```
import shutil

shutil.make_archive('App-1.0', 'zip', '.')
```

from `Release` dir, I get 48 byte `App-1.0.zip` inside `App-1.0.zip` besides the `App` dir. That is it adds this unfinished archive to itself.

Is there any way to avoid that except creating the archive in temp dir and moving?

I tried to set `base_dir` and use `App` as `root_dir`

```
shutil.make_archive('App-1.0', 'zip', 'App', 'App')
```

but I get error that `App` is not found when I set `base_dir`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".......archive.py", line 4, in <module>
    shutil.make_archive('App-1.0', 'zip', 'App', 'App')
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.virtualenvs\....-nAKWzegL\lib\shutil.py", line 800, in make_archive
    filename = func(base_name, base_dir, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.virtualenvs\....-nAKWzegL\lib\shutil.py", line 686, in _make_zipfile
    zf.write(path, path)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1594, in write
    zinfo = ZipInfo.from_file(filename, arcname)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\zipfile.py", line 484, in from_file
    st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: "'App'"
```

The same for `'/App'` and `'./App'`. With full path it works, but I get all parent dirs, not just `App`.

`Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive): _root_dir is a directory that will be the root directory of the archive; for example, we typically chdir into root_dir before creating the archive._ You told it to create the archive in `Release/App` not `Release`.

Comment: @tdelaney you mean my second attempt? Yes, I know, I was trying to add App/ prefix using base_dir.

Comment: No, in that attempt, you were also setting `root_dir` to `App`. The doc tells you that it changes into `root_dir` and then creates the archive file from there. @ekhumoro 's first example works because it doesn't change `root_dir`.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, if I set `root_dir` to `App` and leave default `base_dir` (`.`) then it simply puts all files (*.exe etc.) to the root of the archive. But I thought that `base_dir` simply adds prefix (like `App/`) and this path doesn't have to exist.

Comment: yeah, `make_archive` isn't very good. It uses `chdir` to go to the root directory, so it has to exist (and since `chdir` is global to the process, your whole program is no longer thread safe for file operations) and its documentation is quite confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of solutions that worked or me:

```
# curdir: Release
shutil.make_archive('App-1.0', 'zip', '.', 'App')

# curdir: ../Release
shutil.make_archive('Release/App-1.0', 'zip', 'Release', 'App')
```

Comment: hm, looks like it works indeed. I guess I misunderstood something about that `base_dir`.

Comment: See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943014/shutil-make-archive-resulting-in-nested-zip-files/52301644#52301644

Answer (score 2):

What I learned while fighting with this is this:

```
shutil.make_archive('App-1.0', 'zip', '.', 'App')
```

While 'App-1.0' is technically a "filename", it must be represented as a path to the file without the extension ('c:\myfiles\myzipfile'). I have not played with all the variants for path names yet, so some of the shortcuts likely work (such as: 'Release/App-1.0').

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating the archive in a temporary directory and then moving it to the desired output directory. Following solution worked for me:

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

def create_zip(output_directory, zip_filename):
    try:
        # Create a temporary directory
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

        # Create the archive in the temporary directory
        temp_archive_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{zip_filename}.zip")
        shutil.make_archive(temp_archive_path, 'zip', output_directory)

        # Move the archive from the temporary directory to the output directory
        final_archive_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f"{zip_filename}.zip")
        shutil.move(temp_archive_path, final_archive_path)

        # Clean up the temporary directory
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while creating zip file: {e}")
        return False
```